# Windows 10, getting stuck and unbelievable CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, lag

I've just installed windows 10 and immediately experiencing lags and unresponsiveness. System would get stuck for ~10 seconds randomly. I have no utility software running, or even installed. It is a fresh copy of windows 10 running only skype and edge.

Previously I was having issues with hard disk (SATA) cable so I've just replaced that.

I could see a lot of `COM` related errors in event log but installing some updates probably cleared the log.

In resource monitor, I see ridiculously high CPU usage.

[image]

[image]

I'm running a Intel Corei5 (<s>x86</s> x64) with <s>4GB</s> 8GB RAM and a <s>Samsung Evo SSD</s> Western digital blue 500GB HDD, and am clueless as to why CPU usage would go so high even without having any programs installed.

Any ideas why my CPU usage is 189885288% even on idle?

Also, I've just noticed in the screenshot, `100 Hard Faults/Sec`. Is that normal?? Is my RAM **and** CPU failing?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Ok, I've found a strange thing. The "system information" utility (correctly) detects my CPU as being x86 (32bit) based but the "System" utility lists the CPU as being x64 based.

[image]

**Additional Info**
I actually installed Windows 10 because my previous installation of Windows 7 was stuck in a reboot loop on startup after giving several `KERNEL_DATE_INPAGE_ERROR` with `0x0000007A` error code. That's the reason I changed my SATA SSD cable. I have not run memory diagnostics so far. If memory diagnostics are required, then please suggest me a way that doesn't require me burning a DVD/CD because I do not use any optical drive.

**Update 2:**
Recently I had to replace my SSD and I upgrade my RAM too (increased the capacity to 8GB, to a different brand that I was using previously). So I've a new HDD, new RAM modules, new Windows 10 installation; and and CPU usage issue is still there.

**Update 3:**
Incidentally, I had to run my computer in safe mode and it crossed my mind to check the CPU usage in safe mode, so check I did, and to my surprise the CPU usage was pretty sane.
Below is a screenshot of list of processes in resource monitor. These are *all* of the processes that were running at that moment.

[image]

What gives?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: No; It is not normal

Comment: "CPU as being x86 (32bit) based but the "System" utility lists the CPU as being x64 based." - All 64-bit CPUs are x86 CPUs.  What exactly do you believe is incorrect about the information?  **All Core i5's are 64-bit x86 processors.**

Comment: "I have not run memory diagnostics so far." - You should run `memtestx86` and report any problems by updating the question.  You can burn the .ISO image to a flash storage device.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments. I do not consider myself very knowledgeable in this but I'm mixing up instruction set and memory address width, right? so I've a 64-bit CPU?

Comment: @Ramhound I'll do memtest ASAP and post results here

Comment: I have already answered that question in my previous comment.  Your own [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xxb8O.png) proves you have a 64-bit processor.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled Windows 10 a couple of times and never got this issue. But it seems that it was fixed in build 10041.

Have a read at this

[Windows Shell Experience Host](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-shell-experience-host/32d526c1-e1e0-4fd3-affa-d74f0ef82a3e?auth=1)

Comment: I have `Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 (KB3140741)` as the latest update

Comment: very unlike to happen with this update. Did you try to change desktop wallpaper to a static image and disable automatic color changing?

Comment: I've a static image background, and auto accent color setting turned of already.